# Elasticsearch and S3 bucket: how do I get Python to detect if data from s3 bucket are already in elasticsearch?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I'm extremely new to Elasticsearch and I can't seem to find an answer that will help me to get Python to detect if the data from the documents I have in an s3 bucket are already uploaded in elasticsearch. My goal is to have it see if the data from the s3 bucket is already in there, if it is then skip it, and move onto the next one until it finds a document that has data not uploaded yet. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use DynamoDB to store that kind of information. So each file that you upload to ES, gets a record in DDB. Thus you can always verify if the file had been uploaded to ES, by checking for the presence/absence of records in DDB.

Comment: yeah, i agree. but someone had already put most of the data into the elasticsearch database and i'm not allowed to move it :/ i can only add the new items, but i'm trying to figure out how to get my python code to detect if some of the data already exists.

Comment: @rand03 You have to query for it.

Comment: i was just looking at the docs just now. I'd assume by using this example?  
 s = Search().using(client).query("match", title="python"). Found it from here [https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html]

Comment: yeah, i know :/ i wish i could provide a code sample but it's mainly for work so i don't think i can do that. i don't want to risk breaking my nda. i accepted your answer, thank you!